# polynomial and derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

given real numbers $a_0 , a_1 ,\cdots ,a_n$ such that $a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{3} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{n+1} =0$

prove that there is a root in the interval $(0,1)$ for the polynomial $p(x) = a_0 +a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +\cdots + a_n x^n$ ?!

I just don't know how to solve this question !.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? You even tagged your question as derivatives, which should be a pretty strong hint about how to proceed.... (-1).

Comment: You may want to consider integrals rather than derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q(x) = a_0 x + a_1 \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dots + a_k \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}.$
Then $q(0)=q(1)=0$, by the MVT there is a $ 0 < t < 1$ such that $q'(t) = p(t) = 0.$

Answer (score 3):

If $p(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ then we have $p(x)<0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ or $p(x)>0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ so $$\Big|\int _0^1 p(x)dx \Big| >0$$

But $$\int _0^1 p(x)dx =a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{3} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{n+1} =0$$

A contradiction.

Comment: @Ahmad You are welcome not to accept an answer for reasons of your own. But you posted the question on Math.SE - not in your own class. If you want to disallow some methods, you need to say so IN THE QUESTION BODY. The users have no way knowing what limitations some courses somewhere might have in place.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$q(x)= a_0x+a_1{x^2\over 2} +...+a_{n}{x^{n+1}\over n+1}$$ so $q'(x)=p(x)$. By Lagrange theorem we have in $\zeta \in (0,1)$ such that $$p(\zeta) = q'(\zeta) = {q(1)-q(0)\over 1-0} = {0-0\over 1}=0$$